# Haskell --- error using SplitOn ","

Tags: haskell

```
getLines = liftM lines . readFile

main = do
    argv <- getArgs
    name <- getProgName
    if not (null argv)
    then do
           let file = head argv 
           list <- getLines file
           let olist = mergesort (<=) list
           let splitter = splitOn "," olist
           loop olist
    else hPutStr stderr $ "usage: " ++ name ++ " filename"

loop a = do 
    line <- getLine
    case line of
     "help"  -> putStrLn "print - prints list in alphabetical order\n\
                \quit  - exits program"
     "print" -> do putStrLn "[print]"
                   mapM_ putStrLn a
                   putStr "\n"
     "quit"  -> do putStrLn "[quit]" 
                   exitSuccess
     _       -> putStrLn "invalid command" 
    loop a
```

I'm getting this error:
Couldn't match type '[Char]' with `Char'
Expected type: [Char]
Actual type: [String]

any tips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use single quotes for `char` constants.
[See this](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/characters-strings-and-escaping-rules.html)

```
let splitter = splitOn ',' olist
```

Comment: I tried this, but got another error: Couldn't match expected type `[String]' with actual type `Char'